# Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o, : estimated adjustment 'w' is infinite

Tags: r, error-handling, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I am calculating effect sizes and their confidence intervals for independent groups with this function:

```
bootES( my_data, data.col="Score", group.col="Group",
contrast = c("X","Y"), effect.type = "r" )
```

However, for some of the data groups, R returns this error:

> Error in bca.ci(boot.out, conf, index[1L], L = L, t = t.o, t0 = t0.o, 
>   :    estimated adjustment 'w' is infinite

My assumption was that the number of replicates was too small. However, this doesn't seem to work.

Who knows the answer and can help?

Comment: Please go through the link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37918/why-is-the-error-estimated-adjustment-a-is-na-generated-from-r-boot-package

Comment: Hello, I already tried to type in a larger number of replicates with this function, in this case 10000:     replicate(10000, bootES( my_data, data.col="Score", group.col="Group", contrast = c("X","Y"), effect.type = "r").   But even then the same error occurs.

Comment: Ya its the same for me. Even when I increased R to be equal to 200000 it still did not solve my problem